# What is the definition of "top-level-form" in Racket

Tags: racket

The Racket Reference sections 11.9 Expanding Top-Level Forms and 13.2 Evaluation and Compilation use the term "top-level-form" and the descriptions of the functions **(eval top-level-form [nm])** and **(expand top-level-form)** in the reference manual have "top-level-form" as their function argument, but I'm unclear about the definition of "top-level-form". What is the meaning of the term "top-level-form" within the Racket language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found the precise definition of top-level-form in a kind of Backus-Naur format in the Racket Reference manual section 1.2.3.1

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#(part._fully-expanded)

Answer (score 3):

The intuition here is that these functions all deal with "top-level forms" as opposed to a form that depends on a lexical environment.  As a semi-obvious example, `eval` can only deal with top-level forms, which is why this:

```
(let ([x 10])
  (eval '(* 3 x)))
```

doesn't work.  The usual use of just "forms" is talking about any forms, such as inputs to macros -- which of course can have such references.

Comment: I'm not clear why this doesn't work:  
(define x 10)
  (define ns (make-base-namespace))
  (eval '(* 3 x)ns )     

but this works:
(define (andlist lst)
  (define ns (make-base-namespace))
  (eval (cons 'and lst)ns))

Comment: Those are two separate issues.  In the first one, you're defining `x` in the current global namespace, then you create `ns` as a new one which clearly has no such binding.  In the second one, you're evaluating something that has no *reference* to `lst`, instead, you're just evaluating something that uses the value of `lst` as a syntax, and that's unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: And more comments: (a) if you're trying to `and` a list, then these solutions won't work well -- look at the `andmap` function for that; (b) if you really want to do such things, then you should learn about macros instead of trying to make `eval` do them; (c) if you *really* **really** want to use `eval`, then make sure you read [the guide section](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html) about it.

Comment: Thanks Eli,
Yes as an exercise to learn a little about Racket I was trying to make a function that would do an "and" with proper short circuiting on a list of expressions .  I couldn't figure out how to do it with andmap.  The only way I could figure out how to do it was with the function I wrote down in my previous comment, which took a quoted list of expressions as an argument and constructed an "and" statement and did an eval on it.  I was pretty sure it wasn't good Racket style.  And thank you about the namespaces.  Its much more clear now, though I have more reading to do.

Comment: In this case I'll make one last note: for such cases of learning how to use the language, the [mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html) is probably much more effective.